# Swift - Create variables with different names in a for loop

Tags: ios, variables, for-loop, swift, arc4random

I am learning Apple Swift with the hope of releasing apps for the iPhone.

There are three different 'modes' to my game: 5 swipes, 10 swipes, or 25 swipes. Let's use 5 swipes as an example. I want a variable to be assigned to each swipe, which will be a random integer within the range 1...100 (inclusive). Obviously it doesn't seem neat when I am creating variables in a long list like this:

```
var s1 = arc4random_uniform...
var s2 = arc4random_uniform...
```

Also that could just be a pain when I get to 25 swipes.

So I thought, maybe I could use a 'for' loop. So:

```
for index(in 1...5) {
//create variable with different name with a random integer
}
```

So here's where my problem lies... I am unsure how I would create variables with different names. So: s1, s2, s3, s4, and s5.

It would probably be in the form of an algorithm like:

```
var s(prevnumber+1) = arc4random_uniform....
```

Comment: `Array<Int>`. Also, the language is not suited for deaf programmers - it's called Swift, and not SWIFT.

Comment: Why don't you just keep the result in any array?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Please can you explain what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do it this way:

```
var numElement = 5 // change to 10 or 25 depends on what you need

var array = Array<UInt32>(count: numElement, repeatedValue: 0)


for i in 0 ..< numElement {
    array[i] = arc4random_uniform(100)
}
```

Then to access the first variable, you can do

```
 array[0]
```

And it will give you the random number

Comment: So array[0] will give the first random number, array[1] will give the second?

Comment: Yes. Array uses 0-based indexing